# Eclipse Mars and GWT

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, jetty

I'm doing some update about an old GWT project, moving to javaee 7, gwt 2.7, and so on. Once of the requirements is to move to latest Eclipse IDE, Mars, from the old Juno. Ok, I stardet updating the whole stuff. Now I'm using java ee 7 and gwt 2.5.1 and I'm just upgrading from Eclipse Juno to Mars. Everything was fine, I set up the IDE and the workspace. I can successfully compile my GWT projects by GWT compile. I stumble into a strange error as I try to run/debug those projects. When I run my gwt project, I got back this error stack:

```
[WARN] Server class 'com.myapp.libs.client.gwt.server.PassThroughFilter' could not be found in the web app, but was found on the system classpath
[WARN] Adding classpath entry 'file:/C:/sviluppo/wsmars-r210/MyLibs2.0.0/mylibs.web/target/classes/' to the web app classpath for this session
For additional info see: file:/C:/sviluppo/gwtsdk/gwt-2.5.1/doc/helpInfo/webAppClassPath.html
[WARN] Server class 'com.myapp.libs.client.exception.ServerDelegateException' could not be found in the web app, but was found on the system classpath
[WARN] Adding classpath entry 'file:/C:/sviluppo/wsmars-r210/MyApp2.0.0/myapplibs.ejb/target/classes/' to the web app classpath for this session
For additional info see: file:/C:/sviluppo/gwtsdk/gwt-2.5.1/doc/helpInfo/webAppClassPath.html
[WARN] Server resource 'log4j.properties' could not be found in the web app, but was found on the system classpath
[WARN] Adding classpath entry 'file:/C:/Users/SIGMA6/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jbossts/jbossjts/4.16.2.Final/jbossjts-4.16.2.Final.jar' to the web app classpath for this session
For additional info see: file:/C:/sviluppo/gwtsdk/gwt-2.5.1/doc/helpInfo/webAppClassPath.html
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.myapp.libs.client.gwt.server.PassThroughFilter).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
[WARN] Server class 'com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.server.RemoteLoggerServiceImpl' could not be found in the web app, but was found on the system classpath
[WARN] Adding classpath entry 'file:/C:/Users/SIGMA6/.m2/repository/com/allen-sauer/gwt/log/gwt-log/3.1.8/gwt-log-3.1.8.jar' to the web app classpath for this session
For additional info see: file:/C:/sviluppo/gwtsdk/gwt-2.5.1/doc/helpInfo/webAppClassPath.html
[WARN] Server class 'com.myapp.shared.utility.StrMD5' could not be found in the web app, but was found on the system classpath
[WARN] Adding classpath entry 'file:/C:/sviluppo/wsmars-r210/JSharedP1.2.0.2/target/classes/' to the web app classpath for this session
For additional info see: file:/C:/sviluppo/gwtsdk/gwt-2.5.1/doc/helpInfo/webAppClassPath.html
[WARN] /MyApp.jsp
java.lang.IllegalStateException
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.<init>(JspCompilationContext.java:132)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.<init>(JspServletWrapper.java:96)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:319)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1097)
at com.myapp.libs.client.gwt.server.PassThroughFilter.doFilter(PassThroughFilter.java:403)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1088)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:360)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:729)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:49)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:843)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:647)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:488)
[ERROR] 500 - POST /MyApp.jsp?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997&idSlot=000000001&SID=d2c9ebf6d218c4a5a66aa31f7ca7fd4f43 (127.0.0.1) 3439 bytes
Request headers
  Host: 127.0.0.1:8888
  User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0
  Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
  Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
  Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
  Cookie: JSESSIONID=1wyeek4kpnx2v
  Connection: keep-alive
  Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8888/startup.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
  Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  Content-Length: 125
Response headers
  Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=f7432bsuk10z;Path=/
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
  Content-Length: 3439
```

I'm using eclipse Mars, GWT 2.5.1, javaee 7. Surely I misconfigure something but can't guess what.

UPDATE: I forgot to mention: this is a maven (3.3.3 version) project too.

Comment: `org.mortbay.jetty` is Jetty 6 (or older).  That supports up to Servlet 2.5, part of the JEE5 spec, not JEE7.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you need to set your default output folder to `your-project-name/war/WEB-INF/classes`

To do that open your project properties (you can right click on the folder in Explorer or from the menu) and go to Java Build Path.  Select the source tab. You can set the default folder there.

If you have classes to compile that shouldn't be in your /WEB-INF/classes folder, then then modify the output folder under each source folder that you don't want compiling to default.

Answer (score 0):

In Run as configuration for your gwt web app, if you have not specified the VM arguments then specify it, say -Xmx1024M.

IllegalStateException occurs when the response is already committed and we are trying to add something to it. The reason for this behavior is either the response buffer has reached max size or someone has called flush() explicitly.